# PHP: two values in the case of Switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

If "car" or "ferrari" as an input, it should print "car or ferrari". How can I achieve it?

```
<?php
$car ='333';
switch($car)
{

        case car OR ferrari:
                print("car or ferrari");
                break;
        case cat:
                print("cat");
                break;
        default:
                print("default");
                break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use two `case` clauses:

```
case 'car':
case 'ferrari':
    print("car or ferrari");
    break;
```

The [explanation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> It is important to understand how the `switch` statement is executed in order to avoid mistakes. The `switch` statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed. Only when a `case` statement is found with a value that matches the value of the `switch` expression does PHP begin to execute the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the `switch` block, or the first time it sees a `break` statement. If you don't write a `break` statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

Comment: Interesting to note that the `default:` case is like any other case. It doesn't need to be at the end of the switch. Example: http://codepad.org/jNrQdM3U

Answer (score 6):

You can simply "fall through" the cases you want to handle equally:

```
    <?php
    $auto ='333';
    switch($auto)
    {

    case car:
    case ferrari:
            print("car or ferrari");
            break;
    case kissa:
            print("cat");
            break;
    default:
            print("default");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: How do you respond to the critique by the handsomeGun?

Comment: Sorry, I might be too late, but I cannot find critique from handsomeGun?

Answer (score 3):

```
switch($car)
{

        case car:
        case ferrari:
                print("car or ferrari");
                break;
        case cat:
                print("cat");
                break;
        default:
                print("default");
                break;
}
```

Cases "fall through" until the first `break` statement. This also means that you don't need a `break` in the `default` case.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($car) {
case 'car':
case 'ferrari':
    print("car or ferrari");
    break;
case 'cat':
    print("cat");
    break;
default:
    print("default");
    break;
}
```

This is taking advantage of the 'fall-through' property of the `switch()` statement.  Basically, a section doesn't stop at a `case`, it stops at a `break` (or other operation that exits the function).

I've taken the liberty of applying the indentation I prefer for switches, which makes them only use up one indent level, which I consider appropriate because, logically, the `switch` and its `cases` are all elements of the same construct.  So using two indent levels within the `switch` conveys no useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I dont' know if PHP supports this but in C, you could do something like this:

```
case car:
case ferrari:
            print("car or ferrari");
            break;
```

The idea is that code for handling the car case will keep running until it hits a break statement.  As for style, it should be avoided.