# PHP switch case more than one value in the case

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have a variable that holds the values 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Quarterly', and 'Annual', and I have another variable that holds the values from 1 to 10.

```
switch ($var2) {
    case 1:
        $var3 = 'Weekly';
        break;
    case 2:
        $var3 = 'Weekly';
        break;
    case 3:
        $var3 = 'Monthly';
        break;
    case 4:
        $var3 = 'Quarterly';
        break;
    case 5:
        $var3 = 'Quarterly';
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

It isn't beautiful, because my code has a lot of duplicates. What I want:

```
switch ($var2) {
    case 1, 2:
        $var3 = 'Weekly';
        break;
    case 3:
        $var3 = 'Monthly';
        break;
    case 4, 5:
        $var3 = 'Quarterly';
        break;
}
```

How can I do it in PHP?

Comment: Where does the `1` through `10` logic come into play???  I find this question to be Unclear.  is this question a duplicate of [PHP: two values in the case of Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1383677/2943403)?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The simplest and probably the best way performance-wise would be:

```
switch ($var2) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
       $var3 = 'Weekly';
       break;
    case 3:
       $var3 = 'Monthly';
       break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
       $var3 = 'Quarterly';
       break;
}
```

Also, possible for more complex situations:

```
switch ($var2) {
    case ($var2 == 1 || $var2 == 2):
        $var3 = 'Weekly';
        break;
    case 3:
        $var3 = 'Monthly';
        break;
    case ($var2 == 4 || $var2 == 5):
        $var3 = 'Quarterly';
        break;
}
```

In this scenario, $var2 must be set and can not be null or 0

Comment: `($var2 == 1 || $var2 == 2)` may not work correctly depending on what `$var2` is. If `$var2 = 0` the first case will be executed. It's also a lot more verbose than the plain `case` style. You're also `breaking` a little too often.

Comment: @deceze, agreed, thats why i put the other solution first, its just an example for "complex" boolean comparison

Comment: **If** you were to use this style at all, at least do it correctly by making the condition work correctly: `switch (true) { case ($a || $b) : ... }`

Comment: @deceze if were to do that then `case 3` would no longer work, but i will ad a note

Answer (score 12):

```
switch ($var2) {
       case 1 :
       case 2 :
          $var3 = 'Weekly';
          break;
       case 3 :
          $var3 = 'Monthly';
          break;
       case 4 :
       case 5 :
          $var3 = 'Quarterly';
          break;
}
```

Everything after the first matching case will be executed until a break statement is found. So it just falls through to the next case, which allows you to "group" cases.

Answer (score 4):

If You're reading this and the year is 2021 and beyond, You're also using PHP > 8.0, you can now use the new **match** expression for this.

this could be

```php
$var3 = match($var2){
    1, 2    => 'Weekly',
    3       => 'Monthly',
    4, 5    => 'Quarterly',
    default => 'Annually',
};
```

Please note that match does identity checks, this is the same as `===` compared to switch equality check which is `==`.

read more about match expression [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)

Answer (score 1):

Switch is also very handy for [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). Here is the code for randomly testing four different versions of something:

```
$abctest = mt_rand(1, 1000);
switch ($abctest) {
    case ($abctest < 250):
        echo "A code here";
        break;
    case ($abctest < 500):
        echo "B code here";
        break;
    case ($abctest < 750):
        echo "C code here";
        break;
    default:
        echo "D code here";
        break;
```

Comment: Congratulate you with your first answer! But it's offtop :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use array to store you match groups; like:

```
    <?php
    $names = array('Ian', 'Jack', 'Fred', 'Ismail');
    $name = 'Vladimir';
    switch ($name) {
    case (in_array($name, $names)):
            echo '<p> Welcome ' . $name . '</p>';
            break;
        default:
            echo '<p>' . $name . ' is a stranger to me?</p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bankRemark()
{
    
    $this->db->select('id,status,funding_dt,date,remarks1');
    $this->db->from($this->db_sdip);       
    $this->db->where("amc_remark != '' ");      


    $query = $this->db->get();  

    // echo $this->db->last_query();die;

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->result();    
        foreach($data as $val)
        {
            $id         = $val->id;
            $status     = strtoupper($val->status);
            $funding_dt = $val->funding_dt;
            $date       = $val->date;
            $remarks1   = $val->remarks1;

            switch ($favcolor) {
                case "REFUND":
                case "STALE":
                    if(date("d-m-Y",strtotime($funding_dt)) >= date("d-m-Y",strtotime('31-01-2007')))
                    {
                        $this->db->where('id', $id);
                        $this->db->update($this->db_sdip, array(
                            'remarks1 '     => 'Rejected',
                            'amc_remark'    => 'Check in FD'
                        ));  
                    }

                    if( (date("d-m-Y",strtotime($funding_dt)) >= date("d-m-Y",strtotime('01-05-2003'))) and (date("d-m-Y",strtotime($funding_dt)) <= date("d-m-Y",strtotime('31-01-2007'))))
                    {
                       if($remarks1 = '')
                       {
                            $this->db->where('id', $id);
                            $this->db->update($this->db_sdip, array(
                                'remarks1 '     => 'Approved',
                                'amc_remark'    => 'Office Note Dated '.date('d-m-Y')
                            ));  
                       }else{
                            $this->db->where('id', $id);
                            $this->db->update($this->db_sdip, array(
                                'remarks1 '     => 'Rejected',
                                'amc_remark'    => 'Wrong Funding Date'
                            ));  
                       }
                    }
                  break;              
                default:
                  echo "Invalid Input";
              }
     
        }

       
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```