# PHP switch statement produces wrong results when falsy values are used

Tags: php

I noticed that the switch statement produces wrong results when variables that have falsy values are used.

For example:

```
$total = 0;     // Same results with '' as a value


switch ($total) {
case 5:
 echo "Five";
break;

case 10:
 echo "Ten";
break;

case $total >= 10:
 echo "More than or equal to one";
break;

default :
 echo "Anything";
}
```

The string that gets echoed with this script, is "More than or equal to one".

Can you tell me if I need to do something different to make the switch statement work with falsy values? A link would also be very helpful in case you prefer something like that, any kind of help would be more than welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `case $total >= 10:` ? you can't use an (more or equal than) expression on its own like that, you can only assign; expressions get calculated in `if` and I can't see how you're testing for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your comment. Are you sure that it can't be done this way? I think that it is not really regarded as wrong (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24813225/3915624).

Comment: Note the `switch` usage there `switch (true) { `, not `switch ($variable)`. See https://eval.in/676379 and https://eval.in/676378

Comment: oh I see; well that's a first for me. One never ceases to learn ;-)

Comment: I removed the "solved" from the question's title. If you have your own answer, Stack lets you do that. Otherwise you can delete the question.

Comment: @chris85 `$total >= 10` returns either `true` or `false`. When this is compared with the integer `$total`, it gets converted to `1` or `0`. So it's equivalent to either `case 1:` or `case 0:` depending on the value of `$total`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is true :)  Thank you for the information about how things work here on SO, I still get confused at times.

Comment: @Barmar Aha, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The value being passed in the `switch` is compared against each case's value. In the case of:

```
$total >= 10
```

the evaluation is done first, then compared to the `$total`. `$total >= 10` is

> bool(false)

with a loose comparison (which `switch` uses) `0` and `false` match.

```
var_dump(false == 0);
```

> bool(true)

So the output is:

> More than or equal to one

When not looking for an equal comparison I'd use `if`/`elseif`s, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php.

Comment: Ok that was embarrassing and I'm not sure that my lack of sleep can explain it away. I see what you mean, I still wonder if there is a workaround for the switch statement though (just like there is in the case of the ternary operator for instance).

Comment: Also, I noticed that if/else does indeed work with zeros, but it doesn't work with other falsy values such as empty strings. For a moment I thought about asking another question here on SO for an if/else workaround, but I think I'll just stop the madness.

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement is logically equivalent with a set of cascaded `if-else` statements; each expression you put on `case` is compared (using `==`) with the expression is put on `switch`.

Your code is the same as:

```
$total = 0;

if ($total == 5) {
    echo "Five";
} elseif ($total == 10) {
    echo "Ten";
} elseif ($total == ($total >= 10)) {
    echo "More than or equal to one";
} else {
    echo "Anything";
}
```

Now it should be clear. The first two `if` conditions evaluate to `FALSE` but the third one evaluates to `TRUE` and the message "More than or equal to one" is printed.

Read more about the [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and about the PHP way of [comparing values](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my question about whether or not there is a way to use switch with falsy values (that should be treated as actual values) remains though. I know for instance that this can be achieved with the ternary operator if ?? is used instead of ?:, I was wondering is there is a similar solution for the switch statement.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand your question. `switch` uses `==` to compare the expression you put in `switch` with the expressions you put in each `case`. It does one comparison at a time, in the order the `case` statements are placed in the code, until one comparison evaluates to `TRUE`. If none of them evaluates to `TRUE` then it goes to the `default` label (if one exists). In your example, `$total` is `0` and `$total >= 10` evaluates to `FALSE`. Since `0` and `FALSE` are equal (`==`) according to PHP's comparison rules, there is a match and the branch `case $total >= 0:` is taken.

Comment: You say in the question: *"For some reason it seems almost impossible for me to spot anyone mentioning this behavior online."* -- The behaviour of the `switch` statement is explained in the first paragraph and the second note on its PHP manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I was just wondering how would someone who actually needed to use 0 as a real value and not as a falsy one, overcome the problems caused by this behaviour. One might for instance have a variable called $extra_cost with a value of 0 that should be treated as an actual value. However, case $total == 0 would evaluate to false and the code for this case would be skipped. I do now that there is a solution for this kind of cases when using the ternary operator, I thought that there might be a 'workaround' for the switch statement too.

Comment: So I should have checked the PHP wiki first and not several forums/a/anything, I accept that. However just below the sentence that you copied, there was this one, which was my main concern: Can you tell me if I need to do something different to make the switch statement work with falsy values? 
Thank you for the thorough explanation though, it sure makes it easier for complete beginners to understand how it works.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to put a range in a `case` statement. There is no way to put ranges in the `case` statements. You have to transform the `switch` in a list of cascaded `if`-`else` statements.

Comment: You have a condition in the `case` statement. The condition is evaluated (the same way it is evaluated in an `if` statement, for example) then its value (`true` or `false`) is compared against the value of the expression you put in the `switch` statement (`$total` in this example). This is how `switch` works. The fact that you put a condition (`$total >= 10`) in the `case` statement doesn't make it behave in a different way than it does for `case 10:` f.e. Read carefully the set of `if`-`else` statements I put in the answer. It is equivalent with the `switch` statement posted in the question.

Comment: That is how the ternary operator (the ?: one) works too, there is a workaround (using ?? instead) though that makes it possible for someone to use falsy values that will actually be regarded as real values instead of some form of true/false. I thought that this was possible with the switch statement too. It seems to be partially possible with the if/else statement.. Anyway, I guess that even if such a workaround does exist for any of the statements at hand, it is not that popular. I really appreciate all the time that you spent writing those well-written explanations, thank you once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127963/discussion-between-axiac-and-ctl).