# How to compare width and height in swtich statement?

Tags: php

I have `$width` and `$height`, which are random and represent the video's width and height.

If the video dimensions are greater then or equal to 1080p, it will create a 720p, 480p versions of the video, and so on.

If the dimensions are greater then or equal to 720p, it will create a 480p, 360p, and so on.

And this goes on...

I was using the following if statements to do this:

```php
if($width >= 1920 && $height >= 1080)
{
    // create 720p...
}

if($width >= 1280 && $height >= 720)
{
    // create 480p...
}
```

But I figure that switch statements will be better if I won't use `break` since if one case is true, it will execute all the other cases below without checking.

Is this the right approach? How would I apply this to a switch statement?

Comment: Switch is not the right approach to do this work

Comment: No. using IF statements is better.

Comment: Why are if statements better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using comparison operators in a PHP 'switch' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812851/using-comparison-operators-in-a-php-switch-statement)

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` block is only for variable value comparison. It doesn't make sense in other cases, especially in your case where you have 2 int variables to compare. `If` block will do proper job.

You can do the job with switch (see below), but it's prettier with conventional `if` conditions.

```
switch (true) {
    case ($width >= 1920 && $height >= 1080): //create 720p
        break;
    case ($width >= 1280 && $height >= 720): //create 480p
        break;
    //...
}
```