# How to rewrite this strange VisualBasic switch case to PHP?

Tags: php, vb6, code-conversion

I want to rewrite a VisualBasic function into a PHP function :

```
Public Function Convert_Ariary(ByVal g_Valeurs As Double) As Double
    Dim partie_entier As Double
    Dim partie_decimale As Double
    Dim int_pos As Integer
    Dim Var_Symbole As String

    int_pos = 0
    Var_Symbole = vbNullString

    int_pos = InStr(1, CStr(g_Valeurs), ",", vbTextCompare)
    If int_pos > 0 Then
        Var_Symbole = ","
    Else
        int_pos = InStr(1, CStr(g_Valeurs), ".", vbTextCompare)
        If int_pos > 0 Then Var_Symbole = "."
    End If

    If int_pos > 0 Then
        partie_entier = Int(g_Valeurs)
        partie_decimale = Round(CDbl(g_Valeurs) - partie_entier, 2)
        Select Case partie_decimale
            Case 0 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 0 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier
            Case 0 & Var_Symbole & 1 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 2 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier + 0.2
            Case 0 & Var_Symbole & 3 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 4 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier + 0.4
            Case 0 & Var_Symbole & 5 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 6 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier + 0.6
            Case 0 & Var_Symbole & 7 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 8 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier + 0.8
            Case 0 & Var_Symbole & 9 To 0 & Var_Symbole & 9 & 9
                Convert_Ariary = partie_entier + 1
        End Select
     Else
        Convert_Ariary = CStr(g_Valeurs) & "." & "00"

     End If

End Function
```

I m stuck at the switch case , how to rewrite the different case expressions into PHP statements because there are the `To` keywords ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try greater or equal and less or equal:

```
case x>=0.1:
case x<=0.9:
{do something}
```

or

```
case x>=0.1 && x<=0.9:
{do something}
```

1: [PHP switch case more than 1 value in the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163188/php-switch-case-more-than-1-value-in-the-case)
2:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b203b57e563d9f5921aa89fbefdba0aa1f39d4b7

Comment: Sorry, try like so:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163188/php-switch-case-more-than-1-value-in-the-case

Comment: ok , it works even with the && operator : I forgot to prepend variables with the $ keyword thats why it didnt work ! very sorry !