# this function only adds numbers and I can not figure why?

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

this function only adds numbers and  I can not figure why ?

```
function calculate($num1 , $num2 , $name = "+" )
{
 
  switch ($name)
  {
    case "+" || "add" || "a";
    return $num1 + $num2 ."<br>";
    break;

    case "-" || "subtract" || "s";
    return $num1 - $num2 ."<br>";
    break;

    case "*" || "multiply" || "m";
    return $num1 * $num2 ."<br>";
    break;

    default:
    "";
  }
     
}
```

I also tried if statement and didnt work.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: still dont know what is wrong with my code

Comment: `switch` doesn’t use `||` like an `if` does. There’s multiple ways to do it but the most common is probably multiple pass through `case` items: https://3v4l.org/CkCqQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, do as follows:

```
switch ($name) {
        case "+" :
        case "add" :
        case "a":
            return $num1 + $num2 . "<br>";

        case "-" :
        case "subtract" :
        case "s":
            return $num1 - $num2 . "<br>";

        case "*" :
        case "multiply" :
        case "m":
            return $num1 * $num2 . "<br>";

        default:
            "";
    }
```

By the way, you don't need to break if you return something.

More information :

[Switch case multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163188/php-switch-case-more-than-one-value-in-the-case)

[Switch Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)