# Simple PHP switch case changing output... What am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, joomla, switch-statement

**Main Question:**
*Does an echo output differently inside a switch than on its own?*

--

I don't think this is anything too involved, but it's certainly causing a little bit of headache for me!

To start with something simple, I'm able to show the Joomla full article image like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" />
```

I then wanted to expand this, and add a lightbox to the image, which turned into this:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" data-lightbox="image">
    <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" />
</a>
```

The lightbox works fine.

However, then I only wanted this lightbox to apply to certain menu IDs (I have a News section in multiple languages, and so want to only apply the hyperlinks when certain pageIDs were being viewed).

I decided to make a switch (simple enough!)

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menuID = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

switch ($menuID) {
    case '168':
    case '231':
        echo
        "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' data-lightbox='image'>
        <img src='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' />
        </a>";
    break;

    default:
        echo
        "<img src='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' />";
    break;
}
?>
```

The problem is that the switch is changing the output of src.

**Outside of switch:** /armouredshielding/images/news-events/website-screenshot.jpg

**Inside switch:** images/news-events/website-screenshot.jpg

surely this isn't the way switches work is it? It's still using an echo command, so the output should be exactly the same?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i'm not sure about this but normally the `break` should be in one line with the code inside the `case` statement.

Comment: This layout is how Sublime Text outputs it, it definitely works. Line breaks don't have any affect on the case, as far as I know. But thanks for your advice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383677/php-two-values-in-the-case-of-switch
The layout of my switch is correct. You can have several cases before a break.

Comment: The markup of the switch isn't really an issue, as I know its working, and it works perfectly fine like this in other projects I've created. It's the echo output that's being changed inside the switch, and I don't know why. Can you help with that?

Comment: try setting htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext) as a variable before the switch and call it inside see if that works.

Comment: Tried that, and the same thing is still happening.

Comment: Although it does work when i do a simple img alt echo with the new variable

Comment: Are you doing a "View source" or an "Inspect Element" to check the HTML that's being output?

Comment: I'm doing an Inspect Element, whys that?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something more like this:

```
$pagesToLight = array (168,231);

if(in_array($menuID, $pagesToLight)){
      echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' data-lightbox='image'>
      <img src='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' />
      </a>";
} else {
       echo "<img src='".htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext)."' />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although there were a couple of syntax errors in your reply. But I've fixed them. The problem is though, that the exact behaviour is still happening. The output is different than if I just did a simple <?php echo inside an img tag. Any ideas why it's different?

Comment: Yeah, I missed a parens or 2 lol.

could your objec when called here not be seeing the root of your site?

Comment: But whether its inside or outside a switch shouldnt matter should it? I can put do the simple echo just before and after the switch and it shows the image okay. Just seems to be whenever its inside a switch or an IF statement.

Comment: That's interesting. I've not seen that before lol. I will keep looking for an answer to that one.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I'll just remove it and have a static image